# Implementing PayPal IPN with custom cart use

Tags: paypal, cart, paypal-ipn

I am trying to set up PayPal's IPN for custom cart use. But somehow it does not work. Can you guys have a look at the PayPal button code I am using? Do you notice any problems? Once I click on the Pay button, I am taking to PayPal's page that has the follow message:

We have detected a problem with this shopping cart. If the problem persists, please contact the merchant.

Questions:

1. What is the right way to name these variables: item_numberX or item_number_X? And the same with variables responsible for: price, name, and quantity. Do I need to add the underscore?

   ```
   <input type="hidden" name="item_number_1" value="1">
   <input type="hidden" name="item_name_1" value="Service 1">
   <input type="hidden" name="amount_1" value="148.00">
   <input type="hidden" name="quantity_1" value="1">
   <input type="hidden" name="mc_gross_1" value="148">


   <input type="hidden" name="item_number_2" value="2">
   <input type="hidden" name="item_name_2" value="Service 2">
   <input type="hidden" name="amount_2" value="30.00">
   <input type="hidden" name="quantity_2" value="1">
   <input type="hidden" name="mc_gross_2" value="30">


   <input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://www.sitename.com/thank-you/">
   <input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="http://www.sitename.com/ipn.php">

   <input type="hidden" name="first_name" value="Peter"  />
   <input type="hidden" name="last_name" value="James"  />
   <input type="hidden" name="payer_email" value="alex111@gmail.com"  />
   <input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="144" / >


   <input type="image" src="https://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_xpressCheckout.gif" 
       border="0" name="submit" alt="Make payments with PayPal - it's fast, free and secure!">
   ```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You have most of the button right, the only variables I see issues with are "mc_gross_x", "payer_email" and "item_number".  I am not sure where you got mc_gross_x at, but this would not be used in a button, you may have it confused with an IPN variable.  As for payer_email, again you may have this confused with an IPN variable.  If you are trying to populate the buyers email address on the PayPal payment page, it would just be "email".  Also, you do not need to pass "item_number", since you are using the cart upload method, you would just use the format that you are already using up above in your code"item_number_x".

If the button still does not work for you, I would need to see the rest of the bottom code to see why it is not working.